# Is MS Access 2007 database more reliable than SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Not long ago I developed a Windows forms application to use SQLite. Now there is the need to have the database shared on a network. We don't want to use a Client/Server (MS SQL or MySQL) database because we want to simplify installation of the application as much as possible.

The challenge here is SQLite's performance on a network when shared. The filelocking system is not reliable on a network and thus we can have data conflicts.

I am ruling out SQLite for this purpose and considering MS Access database file (accdb) instead. I am wondering if this can handle concurrent **transactions** say users updating a record at the same time. Is it much better than SQLite.

Maximum number of users should be between 5 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

5-10 users should be no problem. You should [split it into front- and backend](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/split-an-access-database-HA010342026.aspx) if you are not using the legacy application as frontend.